# Invite a non observant Jew to Shabat - Rav Ovadia Yosef opinion

Tags: halacha, shabbat, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, yom-tov, hacham-ovadia-yosef

I know that there is [discussion about inviting a Jew for Shabbos or Yom Tov, where he will drive a car to get there](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15666/inviting-a-non-observant-jew-on-shabbat-or-yom-tov).

Does anyone know Rav Ovadia Yosef's opinion about this matter?

Comment: Why would you expect ROY's opinion to be distinct from those of other authorities on this matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inviting a non-observant Jew on Shabbat or Yom Tov](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15666/inviting-a-non-observant-jew-on-shabbat-or-yom-tov)

Comment: @IsaacMoses He is asking about Rav Ovadia Yosef's opinion as the Sefardic Posek. The answers in what you say is a duplicate give Ashkenazi poskim.

Comment: @sabbahillel, why would Sefardi and Ashkenazi pesak on this be different?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I would not expect it, but that seems to be the question. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 3):

DailyHalacha by Rabbi Mansour writes Rabbi Yishak Yosef's opinion, which he got from his father-

> The vast majority of Halachic authorities disagree, and rule that one may not invite a guest if he will drive. Having a guest show up at one’s home on Shabbat by car, and then leaving by car, causes a Hillul Hashem (defamation of God), in that it creates a public desecration of Shabbat.

http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=1948&txtSearch=birkat%20hamazon